# RAM usage in Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, memory

As my host machine I've got 3 GB RAM in windows 10. I set up an virtual PC with Windows XP via virtualbox. In the virtual PC I dedicated 512 MB of RAM. 
1) When I turn off my virtual PC, does my host machine still use less than 3 GB RAM?
2) Even if I increase the virtual RAM in guest, it still shows the same RAM in host as available? So the guest doesn't take the RAM really?

Answer (score 1):

Virtualbox, (as a [type 2 hypervisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor#Classification)) is a program running on the host OS, so it can only see RAM that the OS has and knows. When you run virtualbox.exe and load a VM, the virtualbox.exe process will ask the host OS for all the memory that the guest needs, and will allocate it accordingly. One thing to note though, is that vbox will only allocate the RAM the guest(s) are actually using (up to the maximum configured amount), not the whole configured amount all up front, so as your guest usage goes up, so to does virtualbox.exe's ram usage.

So the Host OS will see all the RAM on the system, but it will see the RAM allocated to the guest as "in-use" by running programs.